# Nested tab bar with same class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, tabs

[image: nested tab bar with dynamic value]

Hi all,I had an issue on calling tab bar event with different value.since tab bar view get load on single call.unable to pass different values for class.for example,I have to load fri17,sat18,sun19 tabs on tab bar class. it have the content as 17th day value ,18th day value, 19th day value.which must load in list view after passing the date 17 to list class.I had try tab on change listener.still cant find solution this problem.can anyone help me.

```
package com.androidexample.tabbar;




 import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class TabBar extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{
public static String name;

static final String URL =         "http://182.160.161.2/~mani/homeshow/web_serv/timeTableGetByRequest.php?event_id=14&sortBy=time";

static final String KEY_SONG = "date"; // parent node
static final String KEY_IDs = "timetable_date";
public HashMap<String, String> map;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;
String kid,ktit,kart,kdur,kurl,EID;

TabHost tabHost;
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.t2);


      tabHost = getTabHost();
 tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);





     songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    final NewProdCompleteXMLParser parser = new NewProdCompleteXMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); 
    final Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        map.put(KEY_IDs, parser.getValue(e, KEY_IDs));



        songsList.add(map);

        kid=parser.getValue(e, KEY_IDs);
        System.out.println("kid"+kid);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);    
        spec= tabHost.newTabSpec("hhj").setIndicator(kid)
         .setContent(intent);

           tabHost.addTab(spec);
           tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); 
             tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    }


    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_hover);


   }


    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
name=songsList.get(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).get("timetable_date");
System.out.println("on tab changed"+name);




    /************ Called when tab changed *************/

    //********* Check current selected tab and change according images *******/


    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {




        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);  
    }


    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {



        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_hover);         
        }

    Log.i("tabs", "CurrentTab: "+tabHost.getCurrentTab());

    while(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
    {

        Intent  intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);   
        spec.setContent(intent1);
              //Add intent to tab

        System.out.println("on tab changed"+name);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);  
    }


}

}
```

have to send `System.out.println("on tab changed"+name);`. This name val(ie.fri17..sat 18.on each tab click to next Tab1 class)

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

        TabBar tb=new TabBar();
        String name = tb.name;
        System.out.println("on tab changed TT"+name);
     }
}
```

Comment: i had updated .can u please refer @keshav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two better android specific options

1>Use JakeWharton's [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

2>very famous astuetz [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

use this libs and samples do some hacks to load the those amples activity or fragments inside your each parent tabs.

other than this you can do [two way communication between a TabActivity](http://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/two-way-communication-between-tabactivity-and-its-child-tabs/) (i.e. the Activity that hosts the TabHost), and its respective child Tabs (the Activities inside each tab).

gist Code for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
android:tag="tab0"
android:text="Tab 1"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<TextView
android:tag="tab1"
android:text="Tab 2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
<TextView
android:tag="tab2"
android:text="Tab 3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</TabWidget>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:text="Hallo1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<TextView
android:text="Hallo2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<TextView
android:text="Hallo3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Activity:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TabWidget;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SensorActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tabsample);
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();
final TabWidget tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
final FrameLayout tabContent = tabHost.getTabContentView();
// Get the original tab textviews and remove them from the viewgroup.
TextView[] originalTextViews = new TextView[tabWidget.getTabCount()];
for (int index = 0; index < tabWidget.getTabCount(); index++) {
originalTextViews[index] = (TextView) tabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(index);
}
tabWidget.removeAllViews();
// Ensure that all tab content childs are not visible at startup.
for (int index = 0; index < tabContent.getChildCount(); index++) {
tabContent.getChildAt(index).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
// Create the tabspec based on the textview childs in the xml file.
// Or create simple tabspec instances in any other way...
for (int index = 0; index < originalTextViews.length; index++) {
final TextView tabWidgetTextView = originalTextViews[index];
final View tabContentView = tabContent.getChildAt(index);

TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec((String) tabWidgetTextView.getTag());
tabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
@Override
public View createTabContent(String tag) {
return tabContentView;
}
});
if (tabWidgetTextView.getBackground() == null) {
tabSpec.setIndicator(tabWidgetTextView.getText());
} else {
tabSpec.setIndicator(tabWidgetTextView.getText(), tabWidgetTextView.getBackground());
}
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
// tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}   
}
```

Source: [gist](https://gist.github.com/jerolimov/618086#file-res-layout-tabsample-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write different classes for each tab content

and then use this

```
TabSpec tab0 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab0");
         tab0.setIndicator("Tab0");
     Intent tab0Intent = new Intent(this, Tab0.class);
     tab0.setContent(tab0Intent);

     TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
     tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
     Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
     tab1.setContent(tab1Intent);

     TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
     tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
     Intent tab2Intent = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
     tab2.setContent(tab2Intent);

     TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
     tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
     Intent tab3Intent = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
     tab3.setContent(tab3Intent);

     TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");
     tab4.setIndicator("Tab4");
     Intent tab4Intent = new Intent(this, Tab4.class);
     tab4.setContent(tab4Intent);

     tabHost.addTab(tab0); 
     tabHost.addTab(tab1);
     tabHost.addTab(tab2);
     tabHost.addTab(tab3);
     tabHost.addTab(tab4);
```

Also see these

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/